# How to loop randomize javascript function in html

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I know this is very simple question, but I don't know why it only giving same output.
I'm trying to randomize 4 numbers from 1 to 100
I'm very new to javascript

this is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = "",
    i;
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    text += " number " + x;
  }
  document.getElementById("rand").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Generate</button>

<p id="rand"></p>
```

Comment: You should move the assignment of variable x inside your loop. Currently it generates one random number in the range given and that's why you see the same number 4 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your randomize part of code outside the for loop. It should be recalculated on every step of the loop. Something like this

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = "",
    i;

  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    text += " number " + x;
  }
  document.getElementById("rand").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Generate</button>

<p id="rand"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function myFunction() {
     var text = "";
     var i = 0;
     randNos = [];
     while(i<4) {
      x = rand();
      if(randNos.indexOf(x) === -1) {
       text += " number " + x ;   
       randNos.push(x);
       i++
      }
     }
     document.getElementById("rand").innerHTML = text;
    }
    function rand() {
     return Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    }
```

You were trying to print the same random no 4 times. You just need to move your random no line inside the loop

Comment: Explanation of what you did?

Comment: thanks man it work perfectly! now my problem is to make a condition which is to check if the result is not equal to each other so it will give unique output.

Comment: can you mark as the correct answer if it worked so it helps others too

Comment: updated the answer to match your needs